# Software to make ebook read like book style

Tags: windows-7, pdf, ebook

Is there any software out that makes a normal ebook read like book style, where you can flip the pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the source code of the recently launched 20 things I learned online book from google. Its using html5 so the browser must be recent. http://code.google.com/p/20thingsilearned/

This code makes it possible to open the book and flip the pages. 
Example here: http://www.20thingsilearned.com

Update: If you want to read your pdf files flip style you could try Pokat: http://www.pokat.com/

Comment: but where to use this code? I am looking out for some software that handles the similar way of doing this as it shown in the website

Comment: This is written in html 5 and javascript so perhaps its not what you look for?

Comment: No...I need software as mentioned in the question..

Comment: @romilnagrani Check update above

Comment: The pokat is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/), a free and open source e-book library management application developed by users of e-books for users of e-books, which includes a viewer for most e-book formats, but also much more:

- Library Management
- E-book conversion
- Syncing to e-book reader devices
- Downloading news from the web and converting it into e-book form
- Comprehensive e-book viewer [image]
- Content server for online access to your book collection

[image: image1] 
[image: image2]

For the conversion of PDF to e-book format, which is much easier to read on an e-book reader than on a PDF reader, see the free [Mobipocket eBook Creator](http://www.mobipocket.com/en/downloadsoft/productdetailscreator.asp) :

[image: image3][image: image4]

Comment: Calibre is an ebook management software..but where it has option to view/read ebook like book style (flip the pages)?

Comment: I added the View icon in my answer. The viewer is shown in the 2nd calibre image.

Comment: View Icon would just "view" the ebook and would open in acrobat reader... please go through my question.. I want to open in book style..something like http://www.20thingsilearned.com (courtesy: Jarco).. Is that possible with this software??

Comment: I said that you needed Mobipocket to convert pdf to ebook format in order to read it like an ebook. Pdf can not be formatted to fit the screen except via zoom, while ebook text can be reflowed at any text-size. Please go thru my answer.

Comment: Ok.. I have downloaded the software but not sure how to convert Pdf to ebook?? Can you please guide me.. thanks!

Comment: In Mobipocket, check Settings, then drag & drop the pdf on the start screen, click Import, click Metadata to correct at least title and author and on same screen click Save at bottom, then click the Build icon, then the Build button. You will find the ebook in the default folder, but you can also check "Open folder" and click OK to see the folder. The e-book is the .prc file.

Comment: ok...did the steps.. how to open .prc file?

Comment: In calibre, use the "Add books" button to add the .prc to the library. Once in the list, select it and use View.

Comment: ok... but i don't get book-like-view there too....It gets open as pages...

Comment: calibre will convert  pdf to ebook format

Comment: @Mark: I had better results using Mobipocket.

Comment: @romilnagrani: The advantage in e-book format is that the viewer and font-size can be resized and will still display well. The results may not be perfect (especially where images are concerned) but are quite readable. @Mark noted that calibre can also convert pdf, so you could try if that works better for you.

Comment: well this is not what has been asked in the question..!!! dont understand why my question is not being understood...have i asked converting pdf into ebook format??? Thanks for inputs anyways..

Comment: This answers your question. PDF was an addition. The calibre viewer does flip pages. Don't like it? Take Kindle for PC. Don't like it? I'm fresh out of ideas, and you are fresh out of software.